# How do I round a number up in PHP?

Tags: php, rounding

I need to round any non-integers up to the nearest integer, regardless of whether the number after the decimal place is >5 or not.

Comment: Related: [Default Number of Decimal Places to Output in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/357084/367456)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make use of the [`ceil($value)`](http://php.net/ceil) function in PHP to round up.

Similarly you can make use of [`floor()`](http://php.net/floor) for rounding down.

Comment: Similarly use floor() for rounding down regardless. Ceil == ceiling btw.