# Fixing to .2 decimal number

Tags: php, math, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default Number of Decimal Places to Output in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357084/default-number-of-decimal-places-to-output-in-php)

basically a bit of a maths problem,

```
$average_ppm = $total_points_given / $totalvalue;
```

$average_ppm now equals 2.432608695652174, I don't want to display these numbers, I just need $average_ppm to be 2.43, so to a fixed 2 decimal points. How can I do this??

Thanks for anyones time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) if you want a string output, or [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)/[`floor`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)/[`ceil`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) for a numeric value:

```
$average_ppm = 2.432608695652174;

echo sprintf("%.2f", $average_ppm); // 2.43

$approx_average_ppm = round($average_ppm, 2);
echo $approx_average_ppm; // 2.43

echo floor($average_ppm, 2); // 2.43 , even if $average_ppm = 2.439
echo ceil($average_ppm, 2); // 2.44
```

Comment: but I don't want to echo these numbers, I just want the variable value to be to the 2 decimal points?.

Comment: @user969729 Already updated ;) If you want to get a string, use `sprintf`, if you want to get a number, use `round`. Both can be stored in variable values as well as printed out.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf), [round](http://php.net/round) or [floor](http://php.net/floor)/[ceil](http://php.net/ceil) depending on how you want the numbers rounded.

Most suited for your need would be round:

```
$average_ppm = round($total_points_given / $totalvalue,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have ALWAYS 2 numbers after... you can do it with [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
number_format(2.43260869565217, 2); // 2.43
```

When you got a number like: 2.400054846 and you use `round` you will get 2.4
and if you want it with 2 number behind you can use `number_format` this will output 2.40

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php):

```
round($average_ppm, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [bcmath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) functions if they are available where the third argument is the precision

`$average_ppm = bcdiv($total_points_given, $totalvalue, 2);`