# Round 3.33 into 4 using PHP

Tags: php

I need to round up `3.33` value into decimal value of `4` using PHP? Does any one knows how to do it?

For example:

```
3.33 => 4
5.2  => 6
8.7  => 9
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I round a number up in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257032/how-do-i-round-a-number-up-in-php)

Comment: @MLeFevre i wanted to get exact solution. i know you are a senior person of stackoverflow and you must be a genious in PHP. but don't measure all other peoples are same as you. persons who has lack of knowledge in PHP should have opportunity get support from websites like this.

Comment: @JWarker As a senior stackoverflow PHP genius I'd heavily recommend learning to conduct effective searches as your primary method for solving problems, rather than immediately asking others if you have a problem. A search on google for your question title would have given you the answer (from the Manual! probably the most credible source for PHP), and as someone else pointed out the question itself is a duplicate of another asked 6 years ago. Don't slump into that attitude at this stage of learning, take that as some advice, not criticism. I started in the same way, I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[ceil](https://www.php.net/ceil)** function.

*Defination*: Returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value if necessary.

```
echo ceil(3.33); //4
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/WRLkRrtI).

Comment: Could also add `echo round(3.3, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); `

Answer (score 2):

You should atleast google before asking such a basic question. You can use the ceil function:-

```
echo ceil($floatvar_name);
```

It rounds up the float value to the next highest integer and returns the value.