# 7001 write 8? round(7001/1000)

Tags: php

I have to write numbers in groups of 1000.

so, if I have 7000, I want to write:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

but If I have 7001 or more, I want to write:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

php

```
$num = 22501;

$num = round($num/1000);

for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++){
 echo $i;
}
```

if my number is 22501 I will write 1 to 23. but if it is 22001 it will write 1 to 22.

I want to write 1 to 23. how can I do this?

Comment: hint: look at what `round()` does

Comment: `$num = ceil($num/1000);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I round a number up in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257032/how-do-i-round-a-number-up-in-php)